# Jquery mask plugin for currency with units

Tags: jquery, masking

I've trying to build a mask for input text like 'US$ 10.40'.
I tried this:

```
$(".money").mask("US$ ##0.00", {reverse: true});
```

but it doesn't work very well.

Someone here knows how to build this mask?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need this plugin : https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/